# Connecting Rstudio to PostgresSQL

Tags: r, dbi, rpostgresql

I am trying to connect to a external database (PostgresSQL) from Rstudio by using DBI and RPostgres. I defined all parameters:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                      dbname = 'name', 
                      host = 'http://bi-warehouse.cngdka9w0zww.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/',
                      port = 5432,
                      user = 'user',
                      password = 'passwd')
```

but still getting the error:

```
    Error in connection_create(names(opts), as.vector(opts)) : 
  could not translate host name "http://bi-warehouse.cngdka9w0zww.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/" to address: Name or service not known
```

Comment: http is not the database protocol ;) you have to remove that wrong information ;)

Comment: So, the host argument is only: bi-warehouse.cngdka9w0zww.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Now I got the following: `Error in connection_create(names(opts), as.vector(opts)) : 
  could not connect to server: No route to host
 Is the server running on host "bi-warehouse.cngdka9w0zww.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (10.0.1.103) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Comment: in no trading slash, that is not a route of a website :) its only the domain of that server (host) where you have installed your postgreSQL, do you have checked, that you postgreSQL can be connect from external systems, default is only localhost connection allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Try package RPostgreSQL

Example:-

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
psql <- DBI::dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
con <- DBI::dbConnect(psql, 
                      dbname = "machine_db",
                      host = "192.168.13.213", 
                      port = 5432,
                      user = "user", 
                      password = 'user123')

machine_data <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * from machine_db")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RPostgres Package

For More Information- https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres

```
library(DBI)
library(RPostgres)

conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                 host = "xyz-db-postgresql.postgres.database.aws.com",
                 port = 5432,
                 dbname = "xyz",
                 user = "xyz",
                 password = "password"
)

#==== Top 100 Records Of CommodityTable ====
 qr<- paste0('SELECT * from "Cxtable " LIMIT 100')
 Cxtable <- dbGetQuery(conn, qr)
 Cxtable
```